# Firebase email authentication add username and details to firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Currently I'm success with using firebase email authentication to create new user but I want to add username, address etc personal detail to the firebase database. I done all the research of using the uid from email authentication as the child to the node but the code still not working insert anything to the database even the android studio show the database connected. So can anyone please advice me on how to solve this question?

```
package com.example.rex.ota20;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth auth;
private EditText run, rpw,re;
//private EditText rcfpw, rage, , rpn, ra, rpc;
//private RadioButton rbm, rbfm, rbstd, rbtt;
private String usnm, pswd, email, uid;
private FirebaseDatabase db;
private DatabaseReference ref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = db.getReference();
    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    uid = user.getUid();//getuser id

    run = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Run);
    rpw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Rpw);
    //rcfpw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Rcpw);
    //rage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Rage);

    //rbm = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbmale);
    //rbfm = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbfemale);

    re = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Re);
    //rpn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Rpn);
    //ra = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Ra);
    //rpc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Rpc);

    //rbstd = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbstd);
    //rbtt= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbtt);

    final Button br = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Rbt);



    br.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(usnm) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(pswd) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            usnm = run.getText().toString().trim();
            pswd = rpw.getText().toString().trim();
            //confirmpw = rcfpw.getText().toString().trim();
            email = re.getText().toString().trim();
            register(usnm, pswd, email);

            //}// end of validate
        }//end of onclick
    });
}

private void register (final String un, final String pw, final String em){
    Task<AuthResult> authResultTask = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(em, pw).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DatabaseReference dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://otapp-61bef.firebaseio.com/").child("users");
                uid  = dbref.push().getKey();
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Success Registed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(Register.this, StudentHomePage.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}// end of signup

/*private void generateUser (String username, String password, String email){
    User u = new User (username, password, email);
    dbref.child("users").setValue(u);
}*/
}
```

and the rules is

```
{
 "rules": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working xample:

*User class*

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class User {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String phone;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public User(String name, String surname, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
}
```

*Activity method*

```
private void writeNewUser(DatabaseReference databaseReference, String id, String name, String surname, String phone) {
        User user = new User(name, surname, phone);
        databaseReference.child(id).setValue(user);
    }
```

Comment: if like photo also can directly insert to the database right?

Comment: you can save it on Firebase storage. If you need another working example, just let me know

Comment: But if the database rules didn't change as  "true" then cannot set value so I'm just let the database rules save as true?